# Why cannot clang optimize away these unnecessary lea and mov instructions?

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, clang++

Long story short: I am looking into writing a vectorized version of `std::vector` (supporting more than one type) and have for the past few days looked at the assembly from calling (my version of) `emplace_back` in a loop. My goal is for this method to be as efficient as it would have been had it been written in C (see appendix for code). The assembly for vectors of 1 and 2 types looks identical to the C way of doing it but with 3 types the clang compiler leaves a bunch of lea and mov instructions that I think are unnecessary:

```
THE C WAY                                           MY WAY
.LBB61_19:    # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1 | .LBB74_8:    # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        lea     ebp, [rdi - 3]                    |         lea     edx, [rax - 3]
        mov     dword ptr [r12 + 4*rbx], ebp      |         lea     esi, [rbx - 5]
        lea     ebp, [rsi - 5]                    |         xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0                        |         cvtsi2sd        xmm0, esi
        cvtsi2sd        xmm0, ebp                 |         mov     dword ptr [r10 + 4*rcx], edx
        movsd   qword ptr [r14 + 8*rbx], xmm0     |         movsd   qword ptr [r9 + 8*rcx], xmm0
        mov     byte ptr [rcx + rbx], al          |         mov     byte ptr [r8 + rcx], r11b
                                                  |         lea     rdx, [r10 + 4*rcx + 4]
                                                  |         lea     rsi, [r9 + 8*rcx + 8]
                                                  |         lea     r12, [r8 + rcx + 1]
                                                  |         mov     qword ptr [rsp + 48], rdx
                                                  |         mov     qword ptr [rsp + 40], rsi
                                                  |         mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], r12
        mov     dword ptr [r12 + 4*rbx + 4], edi  |         xorps   xmm0, xmm0
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0                        |         cvtsi2sd        xmm0, ebx
        cvtsi2sd        xmm0, esi                 |         mov     dword ptr [r10 + 4*rcx + 4], eax
        movsd   qword ptr [r14 + 8*rbx + 8], xmm0 |         movsd   qword ptr [r9 + 8*rcx + 8], xmm0
        mov     byte ptr [rcx + rbx + 1], dl      |         mov     byte ptr [r8 + rcx + 1], dil
                                                  |         lea     rdx, [r10 + 4*rcx + 8]
                                                  |         lea     rsi, [r9 + 8*rcx + 16]
                                                  |         lea     r12, [r8 + rcx + 2]
                                                  |         mov     qword ptr [rsp + 48], rdx
                                                  |         mov     qword ptr [rsp + 40], rsi
                                                  |         mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], r12
        add     rbx, 2                            |         add     rcx, 2
        add     dl, 4                             |         add     dil, 4
        add     esi, 10                           |         add     ebx, 10
        add     edi, 6                            |         add     eax, 6
        add     al, 4                             |         add     r11b, 4
        cmp     r13d, ebx                         |         cmp     r15d, ecx
        jne     .LBB61_19                         |         jne     .LBB74_8
```

(The spacing in the c way was added by me to highlight the differences I talked about.)

My question is thusly: Are the lea and mov instructions actually unnecessary? I realize that the exta instructions come from updating the end pointers of the vector but in my mind it would suffice to simply write to it once at the end of the loop.

If so, how can I make the clang compiler to see this as well?

If not, why? Is there something in the C++ language that prohibits this type of optimization?

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts :)

Almost forgot, the assembly is from running clang++ 4.0.1 but I also tried clang++ 10.0.0 with similar results.

**Appendix**

The C way looks like this:

```
BENCHMARK_ADVANCED("emplace i, d, c array[]")(Catch::Benchmark::Chronometer meter)
{
    std::vector<int> values0;
    std::vector<double> values1;
    std::vector<char> values2;
    values0.resize(meter.runs());
    values1.resize(meter.runs());
    values2.resize(meter.runs());
    int * ptr0 = values0.data();
    double * ptr1 = values1.data();
    char * ptr2 = values2.data();
    meter.measure([&](int i)
    {
        *ptr0++ = static_cast<int>(i * 3);
        *ptr1++ = static_cast<double>(i * 5);
        *ptr2++ = static_cast<char>(i * 2);
    });
};
```

and my way looks something like this:

```
BENCHMARK_ADVANCED("emplace heap_vector<i, d, c> (no_failure)")(Catch::Benchmark::Chronometer meter)
{
    utility::heap_vector<int, double, char> values;
    values.try_reserve(meter.runs());
    meter.measure([&](int i){ values.try_emplace_back(utility::no_failure, static_cast<int>(i * 3), static_cast<double>(i * 5), static_cast<char>(i * 2)); });
};

...

template <typename ...Ts>
class heap_vector
{
    template <typename ...Ps>
    bool try_emplace_back(utility::no_failure_t, Ps && ...ps)
    {
        auto end = this->storage_end(); // a tuple<int *, double *, char *>
        this->storage.construct_at(end, std::forward<Ps>(ps)...); // template magic that writes to the pointers
        this->set_end(++end); // the problem

        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: What compiler options are you using?

Comment: It's obviously *possible,* unless your analysis is wrong.  Compilers are not guaranteed to locate and optimize everything you might possibly think of.  With ever-improving optimization comes ever-increasing compiler complexity and longer compile times.  And there are tradeoffs, like memory usage.  That's why many compilers offer different *levels* of optimization.

Comment: Optimisation level ?

Comment: Since you're talking about `std::vector` there's no "C way", there is only the C++ way.

Comment: You want the `set_end` to be hoisted out of the loop because it is doing three dead stores. It's hard for the compiler to figure it out because those stores are not actually dead until the unrolling is done (ie. they are alive at the C++ level) and so may be illegal to remove them. Plus there's been a lot of optimization already. The "C way" is not suffering from this because the compiler can figure out the pointer induction. Have you tried changing the type of `end` to something more primitive, do you really need three pointers? I haven't found any flag/pragma that could help in this case.

Comment: BTW, I think this is a missed optimization. if that's confirmed, you may want to write to the LLVM developers. But, please, give them an MCVE they can compile.

Comment: Thanks for all the good insight! Apart from warning options and `-std=c++14`, I only use `-O2`. Tried with `-O3` just now and it does not change the loop.

Comment: Not uncommon to have what humans see as missed optimizations in the compiler output and often thats it, you get what you get, if you want it optimized better you write it from scratch in assembly language or you take the compiler output and start from there.   Of course better is a relative term some folks think less instructions is better/faster/etc.  Sometimes the compiler is just following the language rules and cant remove something even though you might know it isnt used or dont care if it is implemented.

Comment: what did gcc show?  they are often similar, sadly gcc tends to do "better" but gcc has been getting worse since 5.x.x

Comment: @old_timer gcc does not show this behavior at all, with the extra lea and mov instructions that is. Rather, it does something else entirely with the (my way) code wherein it adds an extra conditional jump before every data write, not sure what that is about. Clearly I need to investigate this more for some other time!